# MVC Model data assign label value with jquery onclick function

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

I have an MVC page that takes model data (using a stored_proc in my controller) to provide data for a jQuery datatable. I have a label control with an id on the page. I'd like the jquery ("#Searchbtn").click() event to use one of the model attributes "Model.MetroArea" to provide the label value or text. My datatable is drawing perfectly on the click event, but I'd like to assign the value of this label "cityLbl" as part of the btn click function.

I see many posts answering how to dynamically assign the label value in the javascript click event, but not how to get the label value from the model data.

Here's one of many attempts to put this in the javascript function. I get "Object reference not set to an instance..." every time I run it in any form.

```
var city = new @Model.MetroArea
        (function () { $("#cityLbl").val(city) })
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: why have you got the 'new' keyword there?

Comment: Taking a stab at this...I'm new to jQuery and I'm attempting to get the data from one single column from the first row of the returned json for get value for my label, as in "Search Results for: ("MetroArea")".